# SharedPreferences not saving and returning String

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

My activity contains an EditText which takes name of user as String inout and then I am trying to save this by SharedPreferences, so that when my activity is opened again I can call back my string and set that as Hint in my EditText.

**My code:-**

```
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("Key",0);

       final EditText editname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    editname.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    nameofuser = prefs.getString("name", "Your Name!");
    editname.setHint(nameofuser);

    editname.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener()
    {


        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView arg0, int arg1, KeyEvent arg2) 
        {
            if(arg1==EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE)
            {
                nameofuser = editname.getText().toString();
                   Editor e=prefs.edit();
                   e.putString("name", nameofuser);
                        e.commit();             
                   editname.setCursorVisible(false);
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Here is **nameofuser** is **String type class variable**.

**Now what I want:-**

- At the starting of activity  check if there is any string saved as nameofuser, if yes post that as hint in edittext.
- Later in the program if anyone types anything in edittext and press done, save that string as nameofuser and in sharedpreferences.
- After closing and reopening the application, if nameofuser exists set that as hint in edittext.

**What I am getting:-**
Everything works fine but whenever I reopen the program I get blank at edittext i.e. nothing is displayed there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way,

```
 if(arg1==EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE)
 {
     nameofuser = editname.getText().toString();
     SharedPreferences.Editor e=prefs.edit();  // modify at this line
     e.putString("name", nameofuser);
     e.commit();             
     editname.setCursorVisible(false);
 }
```

Comment: Its not working, Im thinking is it because of some edittext problem or  sharedpreferences one.

Comment: not any error, just no hint is shown in the edittext everytime I restart the pplication.

Comment: All you've done is move from a class level import to an inline one. How could this ever achieve anything?

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will help you

```
  private void SavePreferences(String key, String value) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString(key, value);
    editor.commit();
}

private void deletePreferences(String key) {

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.remove(key);
    editor.commit();
}

private void clearAllPreferences() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.clear();
    editor.commit();
}
private void showPreferences(String key){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    String savedPref = sharedPreferences.getString(key, "");
    mOutputView.setText(savedPref);
   }
```

Comment: Don't post link-only answers. Links get broken and this isn't a forum to advertise your website, it's to provide clear solutions

Comment: this is my blog, it won't get broken

Comment: That's much better now it's inline, future visitors - THIS is the correct solution, not the accepted answer